# IE8 binding event in document.ready not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

This is happening in IE8. I am binding a click event like this in a very general way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-btn').click(function () {
        // do something
    });
});
```

But the `click` event is not getting called. When I change it to `$(document).on()` it works fine. I am aware that dynamically loaded DOM elements needs to be bound using this way. But my markup contains `my-btn` element, so there's no way I am dynamically adding this element. Also, the markup is valid. My `<script>` tag is also added into bottom. I believe this should be sufficient and I shouldn't have to bind within `document.ready`?

Is there any possible reason which may be causing this?

jQuery: 1.10.2

Comment: Are you using jquery version 2.x.x? From the docs: `jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I know the last one dropped ie8 suport http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: I am using jQuery version 1.10.2

Comment: Is hyphen a valid character in an `id` in HTML4?

Comment: Its not only hyphen, issue is there even with underscore or any other ID

Comment: Maybe there are previous errors in the pages' JS that stop the script? have you checked the console?

Comment: Yes, there isn't any previous errors. This is the first script to be executed on that page. Even if there was, how and why would it work when I change it to `document.on`!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but you can try the following two steps:

1. Check IE's JavaScript console, perhaps an earlier script has an error
2. Instead of $(document).ready(function(){});, you can actually just do $(function(){}). It shouldn't make a difference, though.

Comment: I know it should work, but it isn't, that's why I have posted the question. No earlier script has any error, this is the first script to be executed on that page

Comment: Yes, its not making any difference